# Getting null value when pulling data from external api

Tags: ruby, api

I'm trying to pull data from the [WatchPeopleCode API](https://github.com/WatchPeopleCode/WatchPeopleCode/wiki/API-Documentation) and I'm using the [HTTParty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to do this. I pull the data for live streams like so:

```
live = HTTParty.get("http://www.watchpeoplecode.com/api/v1/streams/live")
@live_streams = live["data"]
```

I'm then accessing and displaying information about individual live streams in my view like so:

```
<% @live_streams.each do |stream| %>
  <p><%= stream["id"] %></p>
  <p><%= stream["actual_start_time"] %></p>
  <p><%= stream["title"] %></p>
  <p><%= stream["user"] %></p>
<% end %>
```

Almost all the information is displaying correctly apart from the user. When I test my code in the console I see that the user is `nil`. Any ideas on what's causing this and how to fix it? I really want to be able to link to user/streamer profiles.

Also, am I going about this task the right way? The only time I've worked with API's before is user authentication with Facebook/Twitter etc. Can I pull data from watchpeoplecode in a different manner, or is httparty the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I load the [API endpoint](http://www.watchpeoplecode.com/api/v1/streams/live) then the first data entry doesn't have a user. Whereas the two other entries have usernames.

That said: There is nothing you can do because there is no data returned from the server.

To deal with this you can check if there is a user and handle the situation if there isn't one. So instead of this:

```
<p><%= stream["user"] %></p>
```

You might want to write something like this:

```
<p>
  <% if stream["user"].present? %>
    <%= stream["user"] %>
  <% else %>
    unknown user
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestions. I'll definitely take you up on them :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the API manually (in a browser window) and the first entry does indeed have null for the user.  The remaining entries are fine.

On the live view from `www.watchpeoplecode.com` the first entry is `finished`.

That might be a reason.